# Print the latest three items in the RSS feed with their title and link

Tags: python, xml

I was having trouble with this basic problem for a while and was not sure what the problem was.
The error that I received upon running the following code was:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.11alive.com/rss/local/3/10.xml')

root = ET.fromstring(r.text.encode('utf-8'))

channel = root.find('channel')

items = channel.findall('item')

news = []   
for i in range(3):
    news.append(items.find('title').text)
    news.append(items.find('link').text)

print news
```

Comment: feedparser ftw? http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply slice the the `items` list:

```
for item in items[:3]:
    news.append((item.find('title').text, item.find('link').text))
```

In the above example I also add the title and link as a two-value tuple to the `news` list.

For your example feed that results in:

```
[('The Autism Gap: What Works', 'http://www.11alive.com/rss/article/278819/3/The-Autism-Gap-What-Works'), ('Adairsville effort continues with concert ', 'http://www.11alive.com/rss/article/279178/3/Adairsville-effort-continues-with-concert-'), ('Gold Coast Salads expands seafood salad recall on Listeria fears', 'http://www.11alive.com/rss/article/279147/3/Gold-Coast-Salads-expands-seafood-salad-recall-on-Listeria-fears')]
```

You can simplify your `item` find too:

```
items = root.findall('channel/item')
```

You really want to look into the [feedparser library](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) instead though; it deals with multiple feed formats as well as handling things like caching and sanitizing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop you need to iterate over individual strings, not over the entire list.
To do that, you place the i iterator into the for loop like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    news.append(items[i].find('title').text)
    news.append(items[i].find('link').text)
```

This will give you a simple list of 6 items. `(title[0], link[0], title[1], link[1], title[2], link[2])`